# In pymongo, how to get a set of distinct values from a collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

My environment consists of a mongodb docker container and a simple flask application.

```
MongoDB: 3.7.1
Pymongo: pymongo==3.6.0
```

I tried several different ways of constructing the distinct syntax.
I'm getting empty results from pymongo:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(SECRET_KEY='asdfghjkl'  
client = MongoClient('mongodb://foouser:foopwd@localhost:27017')

@app.route('/get_uniq_ips', methods=['GET'])
def get_uniq_ips():
    db = client.sshnawks
    uniqips = db.actors.distinct('src_ip')
#
# works, returns all values from collection showing src_ip field
#    uniqips = db.actors.find({}, {'src_ip': 1})
# empty sets
#    uniqips = db.actors.distinct({}, 'src_ip')
#    uniqips = db.actors.find({}, {'src_ip': 1}).distinct('src_ip')
    ipl = []
    for i in uniqips:
        ipl.append(i)
    return render_template('uniqips.html', ipl=ipl)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is pertinent section of the the template:

```
<tbody>
{% for i in ipl %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ i["src_ip"] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

What happens when the template is rendered is that the  tags are inserted into the document but without a value. I have counted the  tags returned, its the same number as the total number of documents in the collection.

Am I doing something wrong with distinct?

I tried several other hacks for processing the data returned from find(). However, I wasn't able to see a difference between the original list and the curated list.

for example, i tried this trick for reducing the list to a set:

```
ipl = []
for i in uniqips:
     if i not in ipl:
         ipl.append(i)
 return render_template('uniqips.html', ipl=ipl)
```

ipl list had the same list of values as that contained in uniqips. Meaning, if i removed the 'if' line inside the for loop, i get the same list as I do when its there.

Heres what the documents looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c268d15f5853babff842"), "src_ip" : "158.248.181.217", "interface" : "re0:", "direction" : "in", "rule_num" : "rule 4/(match)", "src_port" : "36790", "dst_port" : "22", "action" : "block", "dst_ip" : "1.2.3.4", "unix_epoch" : "1517220734.472831" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c268d15f5853babff843"), "src_ip" : "223.240.222.100", "interface" : "re0:", "direction" : "in", "rule_num" : "rule 4/(match)", "src_port" : "7496", "dst_port" : "22", "action" : "block", "dst_ip" : "1.2.3.4", "unix_epoch" : "1517222539.564746" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c268d15f5853babff844"), "src_ip" : "195.154.47.194", "interface" : "re0:", "direction" : "in", "rule_num" : "rule 4/(match)", "src_port" : "41609", "dst_port" : "22", "action" : "block", "dst_ip" : "1.2.3.4", "unix_epoch" : "1517222903.470985" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c268d15f5853babff845"), "src_ip" : "103.79.141.180", "interface" : "re0:", "direction" : "in", "rule_num" : "rule 4/(match)", "src_port" : "53789", "dst_port" : "22", "action" : "block", "dst_ip" : "1.2.3.4", "unix_epoch" : "1517225309.861815" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Where's your `client` connection?

Your `distinct` call returns a `list` so why not just pass/return that?

```
def get_uniq_ips():

    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.sshnawks
    uniqips = db.actors.distinct("src_ip")

    print(uniqips)

    return render_template('uniqips.html', ipl=uniqips)
```

Outputs:

```
['158.248.181.217', '223.240.222.100', '195.154.47.194', '103.79.141.180']
```

Tested and works running mongo 3.6 and pymongo 3.6

Comment: Client connection was above this function, same as yours. So, it still doesnt work for me, tried sending the list directly into the render_template, but it didnt work, i got an error from View

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question.

Comment: I ran your code stand alone on the command line, and it works. Thank you for your time. I think the issue lies within the rendering of the jinja2 template.

Comment: ok, i figured it out, it was an issue with the render template. i was using {{ i["src_ip"] }}, but the issue was that i was getting a list back (as you pointed out) and I was trying to place a field into the template that wasnt there, cuz its a list, so there is no key to key off of. i changed to template to use {{ i }} and now it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: `uniqips` is a list so why not just use that? instead of `ipl`..You can just use `uniqips`